# How do I import google visions api into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-api, google-vision

I am trying to use the google vision api in a java project in eclipse. I've looked for tutorials and looked over the steps that google provide but I am still lost. Can someone explain the steps i need to take in order to import the api?